# how to stop the showing error message in visual studio for jscript in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, javascript, javascript-debugger

i am using IE 8 for testing the javascript i write for my web-application. i use something who are not unknown for IE 8  so they give me error each time

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

are their any way to stop this error showing in visual studio when i debug the javascript.

when i refresh the page they give me error in visual studio. well i not want to see anything like showing error in visual studio.

so how i can disable the showing error for javascript in visual studio even i need to work with javascript breakpoint and trackpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I missed something, there's only three things I can think of:

1. Fix the bug
2. Debug in IE with the javascript debugger, instead of Visual Studio
3. Fix the bug

   I recommend 1 or 3 ;)